# Pyserial detect break condition

Tags: python, pyserial

Is there any way to detect an RS232 BREAK condition in Pyserial? I can see options to send a break, but none to receive.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a simple way to do it especially in python, A break is an event, it should be used to reset communication.

AFAIK pySerial supports sending Break, but not receiving.

You can use `WaitCommEvent()` but it's not so easy [MSDN WaitCommEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

From the MSDN:

The WaitCommEvent function waits for an event to occur for a specified communications device. The set of events that are monitored by this function is contained in the event mask associated with the device handle.

```
BOOL WaitCommEvent(
    HANDLE  hCommDev,       // handle of communications device
    LPDWORD  lpfdwEvtMask,  // address of variable for event that occurred  
    LPOVERLAPPED  lpo,      // address of overlapped structure );
```

`hCommDev`   Identifies the communications device. The CreateFile function returns this handle.

`lpfdwEvtMask`   Points to a 32-bit variable that receives a mask indicating the   type of event that occurred. If an error occurs, the value is zero;   otherwise, it is one of the following values:

You need this event:

`EV_BREAK` A break was detected on input.

You have here an [example in c++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)